# How to remove simple product from cart by observer programmatically in magento 2.2?

Tags: magento, magento2, observers, magento2.2, configurable-product

I'm facing problem, I have added total 5 items in cart where 3 items are different colors of same configurable product and other 2 is simple products.

When i try to remove simple product from cart by observer "**checkout_cart_product_add_after**" using `$cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();` method then its change all the configurable products price to zero(0) but the subtotal calculation is working fine. It should only remove the pre-defined simple product. It should not update other product's price in cart.

I need to remove a pre-defined simple product, while the sum of the quantity of pre-defined attribute-set is becomes 100 or more.

Is there any other way to remove simple product from cart by observer ?